# Each Value In An Array * Another Value In A Different Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, math, cart

I'm trying to create a e-commerce style site and am attempting to make basket / cart from scratch. As users will be able to add products to a virutal basket without being signed in, I am doing this process via a cookie stored in the browser. The cookie uses the following format:

```
Product.ID|Quantity/Product2.ID|Quantity
```

I use some code to split the array and remove the '/ and |' and am left with two arrays. One containing all of the product ID's and the other containing quantities.

I need a way of matching up each value in the array to the correct value in the other array. For example:

```
array1 = ["1", "4", "7"] # Products ID'S
array2 = ["1, "2, "1"] # Quantities
```

I need to be able to do Product(1).price X 1, Product(4).price X 2, Product(7).price X (1)

```
At the moment I do @product = Product.find_all_by_id(array1) which does return my products. I then need to do each products price X the quantity.
```

Is there a better / cleaner way of doing this or can anyone help? I DO NOT want to use a gem / plugin for a pre-made cart / basket system.

Many thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this

Lets say your basket variable has your shopping cart value in the cookie

```
basket = "Product1.ID|Quantity/Product2.ID|Quantity"
```

Convert it to a hash by doing

```
Hash[basket.split("/").map{|p| p.split("|")}]
```

Now you will get a hash with product id as the key and quantity as value

```
products = {"Product1.ID" => "Quantity", "Product2.ID" => "Quantity"}

products.each do |product_id, quantity|
  cost = Product.find(product_id).price * quantity.to_i
end
```

Comment: This is really good, except say basket = "3|1/4|1/3|2" so there is three entries. If I run the convert to has command it only returns {"3"=>"2", "4"=>"1"} - Two entries, in reverse order? Any thoughts. Thanks again!

Comment: That's because you have the same product id twice. Hash can't have duplicate keys. Is that a possible scenario in your case?

Comment: I see! No - I need to add some code that doesn't allow the duplication of product ID's. Instead it will just update the quantity. Thank you! What happens if the quantity is duplicated? Say we have "5|2/4|1/3|2" - Will that create an error?

Comment: Duplicating quantity is fine because they become values in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow you to iterate over the first index and get the matching values from the second:

```
array1.each_with_index do |id, index|
    product = Product.find(id)
    cost = product.price * array2[index].to_i
    # Do something with the cost 
end
```